# Can I reuse my S3 custom domain for Elastic Beanstalk by using cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

Context: Right now I have an Angular static site setup on S3, a domain registered through Route53, and SSL through Cloudfront. I have an express backend on Elastic Beanstalk that I want to interface with using https. The EB app has a load balancer and nginx proxy by default.

Possible Solutions:

1. Assign my load balancer a SSL certificate but it seems I can only do this with a custom domain at least through the AWS certificate manager. It does give me the option to use the certificate I generated from the frontend but I'm not sure if that is a good idea.
2. Add an origin on my cloudfront that points to my EB express app. I'm not sure if this is secure or even possible. The idea is that I could make API calls from [www.myapp.org](http://www.myapp.org) (s3 hosted) to [www.myapp.org/api](http://www.myapp.org/api) (EB hosted).
3. Get a new custom domain and give that an ssl certificate and point it to my EB app?

If there are any other options, I would be happy to hear about them.

Comment: Just use another subdomain for your EB app, like `api.myapp.org`.

Comment: I just did this and I think it is working. All good with the one SSL cert tho?

Comment: You can use the same AWS ACM SSL certificate in multiple places as long as the domain name in the SSL cert matches all the subdomains. If not, just create another one, they are free.